# extract content from html snippet

Tags: coldfusion

I have the following code snippet and I'm looking for a better way to parse out the last name.

```
<TABLE BORDER="0" class="info" width="560">
<TR>
   <TD VALIGN="top"> <B>First Name<B></FONT> </TD>
   <TD VALIGN="top"> <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="First_Name" SIZE="16" value="Ashley"> </TD>
   <TD VALIGN="top"> <B>Last Name<B></FONT> </TD>
   <TD VALIGN="top"> <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Last_Name" SIZE="16" value="Smith"> </TD>
</TR>
<tr>
   <TD VALIGN="top" colspan="2"> <B>Company Name (if any):<B></FONT> </TD>
   <TD VALIGN="top" colspan="2"> <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Company_Name" SIZE="24" value=""> </TD>
</tr>
<TR>
   <TD VALIGN="top" colspan=2> <B>Address<B></FONT> </TD>
   <TD VALIGN="top" colspan=2> <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Address" SIZE="24" value="123 Any Street Circle "> </TD>
</TR>
<tr>
   <TD VALIGN="top" colspan=2> <B>City <B></FONT> <INPUT type="text" id="City" name="City" SIZE="14" value="Shady Town"> </TD>
   <TD colspan="2" VALIGN="top"> <B>State<B></FONT> <INPUT type="text" id=State name=State SIZE="4" value="Tx"> <B>Zip<B></FONT> <INPUT type="text" id=Zip name=Zip SIZE="8
```

I have the following but I'm pretty sure I can do this without having to do the replace. What I'm trying to do below is find the starting point, finding the end point, and then taking the text in between. Then once I have that, remove the "matched" text leaving me with the value of the input field.

```
<cfset LastName_start = findNoCase('<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Last_Name" SIZE="16" value="', theString, 0)>  
#lastName_start#  

<cfset LastName_end = findNoCase('">', theString, 0)>   #lastName_end#  
<cfset lastNameValue = '#Mid(theString,LastName_start,LastName_end)#'>
#lastNameValue#

<cfset lastNameValue = replace(lastNameValue, '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Last_Name" SIZE="16" value="', '')>
<cfset lastNameValue = replace(lastNameValue, '">', '')>
<cfset lastNameValue = listFirst(lastNameValue,'"')>
<cfdump var="#lastNameValue#" label="lastNameValue">
```

Any tips on how I can clean this up using ColdFusion? This is an ethical exercise.

And yes, I did try to format this.

Comment: You can look into using JSoup - a Java based library for parsing HTML - https://jsoup.org/

Comment: Not opposed to using jsoup. This code snippet (and many many many more) are inside of a database. Using CF, I can query the content, and pull out the bits I need for each record. Once I work out getting the last_name, I then need to repeat for the first_name, address, city and so on.

Comment: @HPWD - BTW, to preserve indenting in html/cfml, just highlight the code snippet and click the code `{}` button in the toolbar :-)

Comment: omg, thanks. You doing that just made me realize the data in the database is stored as formatted text (with line feeds and carriage returns) and that is why my findNoCase isn't returning the correct starting point. I am expect 295 and the code is returning 308 for the particular record I am working on.

Comment: Heh... the fun of working with white space. Makes you realize you can't trust your eyes...  **(Edit)** I second Scott's suggestion of using JSoup. It's simpler and less brittle than using string functions.

Comment: I'm just going to go poke 'em out now. This was supposed to be a quick project to help my wife create a contact list. The system she is using doesn't have a way to create a list of members with their email address on it so I scraped the member's edit page, saved the data and then just thought I could loop over the data and compile a list. There are only about 100's names or so and at this point it has taken me longer to do the code than it would have just for her to access a member's records, copy and paste the values to excel. Dang.

Comment: Yeah, the first few times creating code to match the pattern takes longer than you think. But you'd be surprised at how simple it is with JSoup.  I was able to grab the names and other values from your example in just a few minutes. If you want, I can post an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second [Scott Stroz's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57544717/extract-content-from-html-snippet#comment101552899_57544717) about trying JSoup. It usually works well, and is very simple to use.

[Download the JSoup jar](https://jsoup.org/download) and load it in your Application.cfc.

```
component {
    this.name = "MyApplication";
    this.javaSettings = { loadPaths = ["C:\path\to\jsoup-1.12.1.jar"] };
    // ... more application settings
}
```

Create an instance of JSoup, parse the HTML string and use [`val()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#val--) to grab the text of the *first* matching element. It returns an empty string if the element wasn't found.

You can find a bunch of other helpful examples in the [JSoup Cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/).

```
<cfscript>
    yourHTMLString = '<TABLE BORDER="0" class="info" ......';

    // parse html
    jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
    root = jsoup.parse( yourHTMLString );

    // get the first matching value ...     
    lastName = root.select("input[name='Last_Name']").val();
    firstName = root.select("input[name='First_Name']").val();
    companyName = root.select("input[name='Company_Name']").val();
    cityName = root.select("input[name='City']").val();
    stateName = root.select("input[name='State']").val();
    address = root.select("input[name='Address']").val();
</cfscript>
```

**Results:**

[image: Image of extracted values]

Comment: HOLY CRAP IT WORKED! Sorry, didn't mean for that to sound like I was surprised! :)

Comment: You just made me a hero in my wife's eyes again. :)

Comment: LOL... I felt the same the first time I used JSoup. "It's really that simple?!?" Glad we could help put you in the wife's good graces ;-)

Comment: Just a follow up question... admittedly I have not read the docs yet, but can you jsoup extract data from a web page if I provided the class or ID as well? I assume I could, in the case of class, it'd just need to be able to identify the iteration I needed (e.g. first, second, fifth, whatever) or perhaps it would just return an array of items...?

Comment: Sure, like `root.select("div.myClass")` or `root.select("##myID")` (pound sign escaped for CF). The `select(..)` method returns an array-like object, which you can loop through.  For elements like div's use `text()` to get the content..

Comment: A lot of other examples here https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Six weeks later and I found another use-case and jSoup saved the day!!